# Enumerating all possibilites for a nondeterministic list

Tags: python, list, functional-programming, list-comprehension

I'm working with lists that could have "ambiguous" values in certain places. The lists are small enough that implementing backtracking search seems silly. Currently, I'm representing ambiguous values in my lists with sub-lists containing possible values. For instance, the list:

```
[1, 2, [3,4]]
```

Could be either the list `[1,2,3]` or `[1,2,4]`. Lists may have multiple ambiguous values in them, though ambiguous elements may not themselves contain ambiguous elements. Given a list with ambiguous values in it, I'm trying to generate a list of all the possible lists that list could represent. The previous list should return `[[1,2,3],[1,2,4]]`.

Is there an elegant way to do this? I tried to recursively build each list backwards and append to an empty list, but I can't quite wrap my brain around how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product`, but you'll have to modify your source list slightly:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = [[1], [2], [3, 4]]
>>> list(itertools.product(*l))
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4)]
```